# MYSQL order dynamic pivot table result by id

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot, pivot-table

This is my query. Here is the [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aa42d/1).

```
set @sql:=null;
select group_concat(distinct concat('sum(if(c.center_name="',center_name,'",w.final_kg,0)) `', center_name,'`'))
from wd_collection_center
into @sql;

set @sql:=concat('SELECT w.purchase_date,', @sql, '
                  FROM wd_leaf_purchase w
                  join wd_leaves_supplier s on w.supplier_id = s.supplier_id
                  join wd_collection_center c on s.center_id = c.center_id
                  WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM w.purchase_date) = MONTH(NOW())
                  AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM w.purchase_date) = YEAR(NOW())
                  group by w.purchase_date;');

prepare st from @sql;
execute st;
deallocate prepare st;
```

Above query generate report with column names from `wd_collection_center` table. Currently column names display in report order by `center_name`.

That means, I have data on `wd_collection_center` table as below.

```
center_id, center_name
20         Pann Center
41         Main Center
42         Vehicle
```

When i run above query, columns in result are as below.

```
purchase_date, Main Center, Pann Center, Vehicle
```

But i need to order the columns by `center_id` as below.

```
purchase_date, Pann Center, Main Center, Vehicle
```

I have tried with `order by center_id`. but it didn't do any changes in the output.

How can i do this ?

Here is the [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aa42d/1).

Comment: where did you put your `order by center_id` ? If i put it in the group_concat function, it's "look like" what you want.

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus I have tried like this. `select group_concat(distinct concat('sum(if(c.center_name="',center_name,'",w.final_kg,0)) `', center_name,'`'))
  from wd_collection_center order by center_id`. But this not worked.

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus Yes. now i got it. This worked. `select group_concat(distinct concat('sum(if(c.center_name="',center_name,'",w.final_kg,0)) `', center_name,'`') order by center_id)
from wd_collection_center`. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Yep, that was the idea ! You're welcome.